# Best practices for unawaited tasks

Tags: c#, udp

I have got a question about un awaited tasks or ignoredtasks.

To simply explain-> i'm refactoring a udpserver program for iot devices.
The first problem here is that the iot device is the udp client with the server ip hardcoded in the udp module and the program is the udpserver.

For each client we start listening on a seperate task. so we have about 100 iot devices which means we have 100 tasks running. Since there listening in packets these are always running tasks and don't need to be awaited.

I'm looking for best practices on how to do error handling on those tasks and also status updates so I am able to check if I still receive packets for a specific client or the task errored or needs to be restarted?

For the last part I was thinking about asking the sattus on each task on a timer tick.

EDIT:

```
centralWorker tmpCentralWorker = new centralWorker( central.node, key, 100, central.emptyOnInit, startInterval );
startInterval = startInterval + 2000; // we will start one every 2 seconds
```

This is called in a foreach loop. for each client start centralworker

In it's constructor we simply have this:

```
worker(workerinterval,startTimeout);  //warning ok - we don't want to wait
```

Were worker is:

```
public async Task worker(int workerinterval, int startTimeout)
        {
            while (!core.startupComplete) { // we need to wait for this to be allowed to start
                log.Debug(name + " -> waiting for core startup to complete...");
                await Task.Delay(1000);

        }
        log.Debug(name + " -> core startup complete");

        //now wait the specified time
        log.Debug("instance worker waiting init time (milliseconds) " + startTimeout);
        await Task.Delay(startTimeout);

        if (core.atlasServer.centrals != null)
        {
            printCentralLayout();
            setAtlasVar(DateTime.Now, "$V." + core.atlasServer.centrals[key].node + ".CommandBusy", "0");  //always set it to available on central instance start
            log.Debug("UpdateDescription is " + core.atlasServer.centrals[key].UpdateDescription.ToString());
            log.Debug("UpdateSymbolLink is " + core.atlasServer.centrals[key].UpdateSymbolLink.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error("unable to output central - dictionary is null - this should not happen");
        }

        //start the timed events now - we are good to go
        askAnalogueValuesTimer = new Timer(askAllAnalogueValues, null, 30000, 3600000);        //wait 30 seconds to start, then every hour  

        //go into the main loop
        while (!core.terminateAll)
        {
            //log.Debug("hi from the worker");
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while (core.atlasServer.centrals[key].packets.Count > 0)      //process all the classes in the queue in sequence asap
                {
                    packet packetData;              //a 'packet' to store the data
                    if (core.atlasServer.centrals[key].packets.TryDequeue(out packetData))
                    {
                        //and pass it on to the packet processing code
                        processPacket(ref packetData);
                    }
                    ++counter;
                }
                if (counter > 0) { log.Debug("processed " + counter + " packets"); }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                log.Warn("exception occurred in queue worker -> " + Ex);
            }
            await Task.Delay(workerinterval);  //now wait the specified time
        }
        askAnalogueValuesTimer.Dispose(); //get rid of the timer
        log.Debug(name + " worker has terminated");
    }
```

The full class is abount 3k lines so.

Comment: You can just use `task.ContinueWith` for example. The continuation will fire when task completes \ fails \ is cancelled, so you don't need to check with a timer.

Comment: Beat practices are sometimes tainted questions, best practices to what specifically? It's what your are doing in your tasks and the code that might really count here and the design there of., maybe if you show minimally your design an appropriate solution may be tendered. However creating a continuation seems to solve the immediate problem

Comment: the task itself is like 10K lines of code. Why I asked. I googled around to continuations tasks and since nothing is awaited or the task doesn't return since it just listening in on packets, I have read that there would not be any error handling, But of course we use logging using log4net.

Comment: If you run some method which returns a Task and you do not intend to await that task, you can either surround the whole body of that method in try - catch, or you can use `ContinueWith` to handle exceptions. There is not much else you can do.

Comment: You might have inflated expectations of what we can do here.. especially without a [mcve]. We can't read your code or design or constraints  :)

Comment: @TheGeneral yes I know. I'll see if I can add something